# "Using" statement in asp.net fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a PHP developer learning ASP.NET, and it seems one has to twist an arm just to do something simple like connect to a database.

When I do the following.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%> 
<%  
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
    //Connect to database
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=MYSQL5003.Smarterasp.net;Database=yyy;Uid=zzz;Pwd=xxx;");  
    //Determine the action we're performing     
    switch(Request.QueryString["action"]){
        case "unsubscribe":
            Response.Write(Request.QueryString["email"]);
        break;
        case "export":
            Response.Write(Request.QueryString["action"]);
        break;      
        default:
            //Default action
        break;
    }
%>
```

I get a syntax error for some reason.

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
Source Error:
Compilation Error
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#"%> 
Line 2:  <% 
Line 3:     using System.Data.SqlClient;
Line 4:     using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
Line 5:     //Connect to database
```

Am I not supposed place the "using" statements in another file?

Comment: how are you learning it ?

Comment: It might seem like one has to twist an arm, but it appears you're shooting yourself in the foot by trying to things with inline code and writing directly to the response. If you want to use Web Forms, use the code behind class and the controls. It will make life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use @Import when bringing in a namespace inline on an aspx page.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
```